# Setting different depth in rpart, but didn't actually change

Tags: rpart

I am tuning my decision tree with different depths. 
I wanted to see my results for trees with depth from 6 to 12.
Instead of creating a loop, I am manually changing the parameter.

My problem is, after I successfully built a tree and change the depth. 
The new tree is still the old one and although it is supposed to have a different depth, the depth is still the same. 
However, if I work on this the next day, the program will correctly build a tree with my specified depth but then stops building trees with new depth parameter.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Am I storing my depth parameter somewhere? I have tried to restart the program and remove all the stored information in Rstudio, but didn't help.

Thank!

EDIT:
My rpart formula is as follows:

```
ctrl = rpart.control(maxdepth=6)
dt_model <- rpart(formula, data, method='class',control=ctrl)
```

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/control-parameter-minsplit-for-rpart-in-regression-tree

Answer (score 5):

It is strange what you are seeing. The only thing I can think without seeing your rpart statement is that you didn't use the list command in the control statement. Also check if their is an effect from minsplit and minbucket on your tree build.

```
# this doesn't work
fit <- rpart(class ~ ., data = df, method = "class", control = ("maxdepth = 1"))

# changing maxdepth here effects your tree depth. 
rpart(class ~ ., data = df, method = "class", control = list(maxdepth = 1))
```

Comment: thanks phiver and sorry that I didn't include my code. For my rpart formula, I set ctrl = rpart.control(maxdepth=6). dt_model <- rpart(formula, data, method='class',control=ctrl).    I just checked your method where I put the maxdepth in a list in control, but still the result if a 8-depth tree

Comment: What is your sample size and distribution of `class`?  Single tree methods require enormous sample sizes to be reliable.

Comment: @jason: did you study the answer of phiver and changed *all* relevant options like minbucket etc.? They may contradict each other.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I have an extremely skewed dataset. And thus I oversampled my target data. Anyway, my final dataset has over 2 million rows, and class distribution is 50:50. Sometimes I can set the depth to 10 and returns a tree with 11 nodes (root node counted) and sometimes I can't reproduce this 11-node tree, if I have produced a 6-depth tree before it. And nor can I produce a 4-depth tree

Comment: @MichaelM, No, for minbucket, I haven't. I have tried ctrl = rpart.control(maxdepth=6, minsplit = 0, cp=0). And the resulting tree just grows to its full depth.. Am I contradicting myself with maxdepth = 6 and cp=0 ?

Comment: @MichaelM I just realized that once I set the maxdepth = 6(or any other sensible number), any tree I built will be of the same depth, no matter how I change the depth. And even if I build a new tree without specifying the depth, the tree is of depth 6.

Comment: There is no need to sample the dataset, and sampling will destroy the ability to estimate probabilties.  Don't use just dichotomous classifications.  Make sure you are using an efficient splitting test such as one based on deviance (log likelihood) an efficient score statistic (sometimes this is Pearson's chi-square).

Comment: @FrankHarrell I misunderstood the meaning of maxdepth... Now I figured out. And for your previous comment, actually sampling is the best thing I can do now. I don't need the probabilities, I just need the model to reliably predict 1 and 0 for the unsampled test set. For my training set, if I don't oversample/undersample, decision tree or logistic regression will always predict 0 for me because less than 0.1% of the data is 1.

Comment: @MichaelM, thanks, I just realized that I was misunderstanding the meaning of maxdepth. Now I understood.

Comment: Don't use a 'decision' or 'classification'.  This is arbitrary and will not (1) properly transport to other situations where the sampling is different nor (2) allow for gray 'no decision' zones.  Your approach also uses a very strange loss/utility function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set cp=0 in the controls the complexity of the tree. If cp>0 the tree won't grown unless the increase in tree size doesn't improve the performance of the tree by at least cp.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, max depth is not a stopping criteria in rpart source code, the corresponding max node number is a stopping criteria for growing the tree.
for example, if max depth=6, the corresponding stopping rule will be, "if total nodes > (2^6 - 1), the tree will stop growing".

And for your issue, I couldn't reproduce it. I am using R version 3.3.0 and the most recent rpart.